# Responsiveness problem of a multi-item carrousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, responsive

Following my previous topic on another carousel, I changed the carousel.

The new one that I took from a snippet available here: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dl6ez , this one is very responsive, on the other hand when I apply it on my project (which I can only show 'to image, since I only changed the image path).

But my problem is that it only displays a single image (in mobile version is normal), but in desktop version it doesn't enlarge.

Original snippet PC version:
[snippet origine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmhEX.png)

Original snippet responsive version:
[origine snippet responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsDXp.png) (Animate when you go to the link I mentioned).

My smartphone version carrousel:
[my carrousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMhuf.png) with animation.
The display on PC:

[version desktop capture non animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGAGa.png)

It keeps the animation, house not enlarged according to the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't change a thing
the display remains the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
                    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3  active">
                           <div class="panel panel-default">
                              <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                                <a href="#" title="image 1" class="thumb">
                                  <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="images/housse de couette 20 balles/avengers 1.jpg" alt="slide 1"></a>
                                  <p style="color: gray;text-decoration:line-through;">22.99€</p>
                                    <h4 id="prix" style="color:red; align-content:right;">11.99€</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                           <div class="panel panel-default">
                              <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                                <a href="#" title="image 3" class="thumb">
                                 <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="images/housse de couette 20 balles/cars 1.jpg" alt="slide 2"></a>
                                  <p style="color: gray;text-decoration:line-through;">22.99€</p>
                                    <h4 id="prix" style="color:red; align-content:right;">11.99€</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                           <div class="panel panel-default">
                              <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                                <a href="#" title="image 4" class="thumb">
                                 <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="images/housse de couette 20 balles/fee clochette.JPG" alt="slide 3"></a>
                                  <p style="color: gray;text-decoration:line-through;">22.99€</p>
                                    <h4 id="prix" style="color:red; align-content:right;">11.99€</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                              <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                                <a href="#" title="image 5" class="thumb">
                                 <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="images/housse de couette 20 balles/princess.JPG" alt="slide 4"></a>
                                  <p style="color: gray;text-decoration:line-through;">22.99€</p>
                                    <h4 id="prix" style="color:red; align-content:right;">11.99€</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                          <div class="panel panel-default">
                              <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                                <a href="#" title="image 6" class="thumb">
                                  <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="images/housse de couette 20 balles/sofia 1.JPG" alt="slide 5"></a>
                                  <p style="color: gray;text-decoration:line-through;">22.99€</p>
                                    <h4 id="prix" style="color:red; align-content:right;">11.99€</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                           <div class="panel panel-default">
                              <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                                <a href="#" title="image 7" class="thumb">
                                  <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="images/housse de couette 20 balles/sofia 2.JPG" alt="slide 6"></a>
                                  <p style="color: gray;text-decoration:line-through;">22.99€</p>
                                    <h4 id="prix" style="color:red; align-content:right;">11.99€</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

/* show 3 items */
.carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item  {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    transition: none;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* left or forward direction */
.active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
}

/* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* right or prev direction */
.active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

}

For the JS I took the code from: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dl6ez without modifying it

Answer (score 0):

Repply for bootsnip :

I add:

```
.carousel-item {margin-right: auto !important;}
```

and it works for me

Answer (score -1):

Basically, it is not support zoom mode for desktop view, In mobile view method, what it's active normally zoom method is because apple device.

Comment: I am on windows, and i use the snippet which works fine except for me, so i just change the image path and nothing else. And this I do not understand.

Comment: yeah, make sense, If so, it should be biggest animation area to control with zoom method. so you can access with zoom method.

Comment: But I'm not looking for that, what I want is that when I'm on pc it shows all lined up, and when I'm on mobile it shows one by one.

So when I'm on mobile it works, but on desktop it leaves it in the mobile version and doesn't develop the carousel down the line.

Comment: Of course, it is responsive for mobile desktop view. Because use Bootstrap, it is changing with pixel. thus the carousel numbers will change with pixel.

Comment: I don't understand the original snippet link works, and in my house it doesn't.
From the mobile version, it does not return to the desired display on desktop. And already the desktop version does not work (does not display it as I want).